# Spring, EclipseLink, Jboss eap 7 with XA datasource

Tags: java, spring, jboss, eclipselink, jboss-eap-7

We are migrating this application from Weblogic to Jboss.
Application works in weblogic XA datasource or even in Jboss with Non-XA.. But its not working in Jboss XA datasource....

Getting following exception in Jboss XA datasource

```
2018-11-02 15:04:34,003 ERROR [com.hf.pi.esign.dao.db.ActivityDBDAOImpl] (default-threads - 4) ERROR SAVING ENTITY :: com.hf.pi.esign.dao.db.entity.OpportunityEntity@4753c567 For id :: null: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
        Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031017: You cannot set autocommit during a managed transaction
        Error Code: 0
        Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.hf.pi.esign.dao.db.entity.OpportunityEntity@4753c567)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:879)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.hf.pi.esign.dao.db.ActivityDBDAOImpl.saveEntity(ActivityDBDAOImpl.java:122)
    at com.hf.pi.esign.dao.db.ActivityDBDAOImpl.saveOpportunity(ActivityDBDAOImpl.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.saveOpportunity(Unknown Source)
    at com.hf.pi.esign.service.profile.ProfileServiceImpl.saveConsumerOpportunity(ProfileServiceImpl.java:124)
    at com.hf.pi.esign.service.esignstatusnotification.StatusNotificationServiceImpl.logOpportunity(StatusNotificationServiceImpl.java:237)
    at com.hf.pi.esign.service.esignstatusnotification.StatusNotificationServiceImpl.process(StatusNotificationServiceImpl.java:371)
    at com.hf.pi.esign.service.esignstatusnotification.StatusNotificationServiceImpl.processNotificationStatusInternal(StatusNotificationServiceImpl.java:203)
    at com.hf.pi.esign.service.esignstatusnotification.StatusNotificationServiceImpl.processNotificationStatus(StatusNotificationServiceImpl.java:113)
    at com.hf.pi.esign.mdb.StatusNotificationProcessor.process(StatusNotificationProcessor.java:87)
    at com.hf.pi.esign.mdb.AbstractConsumerMDB.onMessageInternal(AbstractConsumerMDB.java:90)
    at com.hf.pi.esign.mdb.StatusNotificationProcessor.onMessage(StatusNotificationProcessor.java:155)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:255)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:334)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:240)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbSuspendInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbSuspendInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentDescription$5$1.processInvocation(MessageDrivenComponentDescription.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:609)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
    at com.hf.pi.esign.mdb.StatusNotificationProcessor$$$view2.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:139)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.hf.pi.esign.mdb.StatusNotificationProcessor$$$endpoint1.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointWrapper.onMessage(MessageEndpointWrapper.java:151)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession$FacadeMessageListener.onMessage(MQSession.java:129)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.run(JmsSessionImpl.java:3250)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.run(MQSession.java:937)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ASFWorkImpl.doDelivery(ASFWorkImpl.java:104)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.AbstractWorkImpl.run(AbstractWorkImpl.java:233)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.workmanager.WorkWrapper.runWork(WorkWrapper.java:445)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.services.workmanager.WildflyWorkWrapper.runWork(WildflyWorkWrapper.java:68)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.workmanager.WorkWrapper.run(WorkWrapper.java:223)
    at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:808)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:828)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..
    Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031017: You cannot set autocommit during a managed transaction
    Error Code: 0
    Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.hf.pi.esign.dao.db.entity.OpportunityEntity@4753c567)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicBeginTransaction(DatabaseAccessor.java:245)
    ..
    ..
        ... 103 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031017: You cannot set autocommit during a managed transaction
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.setJdbcAutoCommit(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:973)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.setAutoCommit(WrappedConnection.java:787)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicBeginTransaction(DatabaseAccessor.java:238)
        ... 133 more
```

datasource is configured as

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/esign_cons_ds" pool-name="esign_cons_ds">
                    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
                        jdbc:oracle:thin:@database:1521/ease.world
                    </xa-datasource-property>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <xa-pool>
                        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>15</max-pool-size>
                    </xa-pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>username</user-name>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                        <use-fast-fail>true</use-fast-fail>
                        <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                </xa-datasource>
```

JPA is configured in PersistenceJPAConfig as

```
@Configuration
@Import(EnvironmentConfig.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig implements BeanFactoryAware{
    /** Logger*/
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(PersistenceJPAConfig.class);

    /** JNDI Name*/
    private static final String DATA_SOURCE_JNDI_NAME = "consumer.datasource.jndi.name";
    /** DAO Scan packages*/
    private static final String[] DAO_PACKAGE = { "com.hf.pi.esign.dao.*","com.hf.pi.esign.dao.db.entity.*" };
    /** beanFactory*/
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }
    private Environment getEnv(){
        return this.beanFactory.getBean(EnvironmentConfig.class).getEnv();
    }

    private String getDataSourceName(){
        String dataSourceName = getEnv().getProperty(DATA_SOURCE_JNDI_NAME);
        LOG.info("Consumer JPA config ressolved jndi name : "+dataSourceName);
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(dataSourceName)){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid data source name from property file "+DATA_SOURCE_JNDI_NAME);
        }
        return dataSourceName;
    }

    /**
     * EntityManager is set up by creating a Spring factory bean to manage it;
     * this will allow the PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor to retrieve it
     * from the Container.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(DAO_PACKAGE);

        // Do not import Eclipse JPA Provider directly here
        // (org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider)
        // Using Spring Adapter for EclipseLink
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        // JPA properties usually specified in persistence.xml file is imported
        // using below statement
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = null;

        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(getDataSourceName());
        } catch (NamingException ne) {
            LOG.error(ne);
        }

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

        // set the EntityManagerFactory that this instance should manage
        // transactions for
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(this
                .entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }


    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties defaultProperties = new Properties();
        defaultProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", "false");
        try {
            LOG.info("loading eclipselink props");
            Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/eclipselink.properties");
            defaultProperties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
            LOG.info("eclipselink:" + defaultProperties);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error(e);
        }
        return defaultProperties;
    }

}
```

eclpipselink.properties

```
##This is EclipseLink Configuration File
eclipselink.logging.level=INFO

#enable weaving i.e. byte code instrumentation used by EclipseLink
eclipselink.weaving=false

#Caching Disabled as limitation of the shared cache, is that if the database
#is changed directly through JDBC, or by another application or server, 
#the objects in the shared cache will be stale
eclipselink.cache.shared.default=false

#performance related properties - for future optimization

#Optimization - avoid auto flush cost on query execution 
eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode=commit

#Optimization - close EntityManager on commit, to avoid cost of resume 
eclipselink.persistence-context.close-on-commit=true

#Optimization - avoid cost of persist on commit 
#eclipselink.persistence-context.persist-on-commit=false
```

Should i change below implementation from JPA to JTA to solve this issue?

```
@Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

        // JtaTransactionManager.
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

        // set the EntityManagerFactory that this instance should manage
        // transactions for
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(this
                .entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

to

```
@Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

        // JtaTransactionManager.
        JtaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();


        return transactionManager;
    }
```

Comment: "Schemaupdate needs to be able to grab the transaction and commit, that cannot be the case in CMT where only the container has access to transaction",Have you set transaction  auto commit or auto update to true somewhere if so try disabling it,that should probably resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have changed JPATransactionManager to JTATransactionManager and also set the datasources in LocalEntityManager as jtaDatasource to solve the issue.

```
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

        // JtaTransactionManager.
        JtaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();


        return transactionManager;
    }




@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            em.seJtatDataSource(dataSource());
...
...
}
```